# How to set sourceCompatability to javaVersion.VERSION_1_8

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

I installed jdk1.8.0_112 and write code below in build.gradle

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

i received this error

```
Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I didn't realise I'm required to support java 8 language features. Thanks for the heads-up ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html, you also need following:

```
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE**

Note that Jack toolchain is now deprecated https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio 3.0 Preview 1 and later supports all Java 7 language features and a subset of Java 8 language. **Jack is no longer supported**, and you should first disable Jack to use the improved Java 8 support built into the default toolchain.

From:
[Use Java 8 language features](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}
```